# Как сделать кастомный скроллбар в react

Tags: reactjs, scrollbar

пытался сделать [image: введите сюда описание изображения]с помощью simplebar-react, но там скорлл просто зависал в середине

Comment: Выбирай - https://www.cssscript.com/best-custom-scrollbar-javascript-libraries/

Comment: Еще вот такой модуль для этого есть - https://github.com/Grsmto/simplebar